# Create action is called by every button (not only "submit" one)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have a form for transaction, with some text and select fields. There is a text-field `date`, where I use `jQuery.ui.datepicker`. I've hidden text-field and use buttons instead ("today", "yesterday", and "calendar-icon" buttons). "Yesterday" and "today" buttons change the value of hidden field, but also they call `submit` action and create the transaction if other fields are filled or cause Internal Server Error with status 500. I need to call `create` action only by click on `submit` button.

This is create action of `transaction_controller.rb`

```
def create
    if @transaction.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.js
      end
    else
      render 'pages/index'
    end
  end
```

This is `transaction_form` for `new` transaction action.

```
<%= form_for @transaction, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="form-row">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'input-medium', 'placeholder' => 'Name' %>
      <%= f.text_field :amount, class: 'input-small', 'placeholder' => '$' %>
      <%= f.submit 'Add', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>

    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, current_user.categories.all, :id, :name, {}, class: 'input-medium' %>
    <%= f.collection_select :account_id, current_user.accounts.all, :id, :name, {}, class: 'input-small' %>
    <%= f.text_field :date, 'value' => Date.today %>

    <div class="btn-group" id="transaction_date_group">
      <button class="btn active" id="transaction_today">Today</button>
      <button class="btn" id="transaction_yesterday">Yesterday</button>
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="transaction_date_dropdown">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
      </button>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

This is `create.js.erb`

```
$('#transactions_table').prepend('<%= j render(@transaction) %>');
$('#new_transaction').each(function () {
    this.reset();
});
<% if @transaction.category_id == current_user.categories.first.id && current_user.categories.first.balance == @transaction.amount %>
$('#categories_table').append('<%= j render(@category) %>');
<% end %>
$('#edit_category_<%= @transaction.category_id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render(@category) %>');
$('#edit_category_<%= @transaction.category_id %>').hide().fadeIn('slow');
$('#edit_account_<%= @transaction.account_id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render(@account) %>');
$('#edit_account_<%= @transaction.account_id %>').hide().fadeIn('slow');
$('#accounts_total').replaceWith('<td id="accounts_total"><%= current_user.accounts.sum(:balance) %></td>');
$('#accounts_total').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

And this is `transaction.js.coffee`, which is used for `datepicker` showing and changing classes of buttons, while clicking.

```
jQuery ->
  $("#transaction_date").datepicker dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"

  $("#transaction_date_dropdown").click ->
    if $("#transaction_date_group").hasClass 'open'
      $("#transaction_date").datepicker 'hide'
    else
      $("#transaction_date").datepicker 'show'
      $("#transaction_today").removeClass 'active'
      $("#transaction_yesterday").removeClass 'active'

  $("#transaction_yesterday").click ->
    $("#transaction_today").removeClass 'active'
    $("#transaction_yesterday").addClass 'active'
    yesterday = moment().add('days', -1).format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    $("#transaction_date").val yesterday

  $("#transaction_today").click ->
    $("#transaction_yesterday").removeClass 'active'
    $("#transaction_today").addClass 'active'
    today = moment().format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    $("#transaction_date").val today
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.html):

> A `button` element with no `type` attribute specified represents the same thing as a `button` element with its `type` attribute set to `"submit"`.

So this:

```
<button class="btn active" id="transaction_today">Today</button>
```

is, in fact, a submit button and submit buttons submit forms. If you don't want your `<button>`s submitting for your form, say so by using a [`type="button"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.button.html#button.button) button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn active" id="transaction_today">Today</button>
```

Some older IEs default to `type="button"` despite (or in spite) of what the specification says so you should **always** specify the `type` attribute when you use a `<button>`.

Comment: Thanks! Method with `return false` is also working, but I think this one, with `type="button"`, is more correct.

Comment: Using `return false` is fine as long as you know what's going, I added an answer to make sure you know what's going on. Oddly enough, I think this is the correct answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

Add return false in every click event callbacks

```
$("#transaction_yesterday").click ->
  ..
  $("#transaction_date").val yesterday
  return false
```